# PHP Time to String from SQL Server value doesn't match

Tags: php

I have a table with one record, there is a column which is `time` formatted.

The real value inside it is `23:15:12.1170000`, but when I try to get the data in PHP, it shows me `23:03:12`.

The question is, why the output is not match ? Could somebody help me please ? Do I need to include the timezone set before parsing it ?

EDIT : I mean the Hour, Minute, Second value ( The number ). not the format I converted into.

This is my conversion code :
`<?= date_format( $row["time"], "H:m:s" ) ?>`

Comment: because you specifically told it to use the format `"H:m:s"`, so it only displays the hours, minutes and seconds. If you want another format, use another format. The formats accepted by date_format() are the same as those accepted by date(), and are listed in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's not what i mean sir. The point of my question is why the hour, minute, and second is not match with real values from the database

Comment: It seems almost impossible that that could be the case. Are you _certain_ it's reading the same row and column?

Comment: Yes, same row, same table. The column was time formatted like I said.

Comment: How are you seeing the "real" time exactly? You ran the query in SSMS separately or something? Show us the SQL query, and how exactly you're calling it in PHP. Screenshot of the table data from SSMS would also be interesting

Comment: sure, give me a moment sir, my connection is bzzzt, too scary to explain.

Comment: here is the screenshot sir.. [https://ibb.co/cuUw7x](https://ibb.co/cuUw7x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the time format: `m` represents month and not minutes, use `i` for minutes.

```
<?= date_format( $row["time"], "H:i:s" ) ?>
```

Comment: Ghost! that was insane.. Thanks for the help sir, I did not realized that I put the wrong format on my code. thanks a lot! :D